# How can I save a Future instance for later use

Tags: java, spring, persistence, future

Assume I have a method that returns a Future. For example:

```
void foo() {
    final Future<String> future = bar();
    save(future, "FOO");
}

void fooCancel() {
    final Future<String> future = load("FOO");
    future.cancel();
}
```

Is there a good way to persist the future? I could use something simple like a Map<String, Future> but that seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: Are you saying you want to store the `Future` in a database or a file system, or something like that?

Comment: If you mean persist in memory, why is the map a bad idea?

Comment: "persist in memory" = "refer to with a variable", just like any other kind of object.

Comment: Let me rephrase. We want to be able to launch asynchronous code that may need to be cancelled and restarted. The client can't block, so putting in code to wait for a Future to complete is not an option. Is it possible to save a thread id (to REDIS for example) so that we can retrieve the thread later in case it needs to be cancelled?

Comment: Rather than post a Comment, edit the body of your Question for clarity. And explain what you mean by "The client can't block, so putting in code to wait for a Future to complete is not an option.". I suspect you misunderstand some key concepts of threading/concurrency.

Comment: A thread is a runtime-only kind of thing. Persisting makes no sense.